# How to differentiate and replace the span text on mouse over

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a table structure like this with out any ID and span has same text.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <span>Name</span>
      </td>
      <td>
          <span>Name</span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If i click on first span this will open a pop up. Pop up contains text box and Button.If i type some text and click the button, the clicked span should replace with newly entered text. how can i identify the clicked span and replace the text?.

The same way we need to do for second span.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you add a click event in your span, you will have the tag reference with "this". Then if you call .text() on it, the related tag will be updated.

like that :

```
$('span').click(function() {
    $(this).text('new text');
})
```

Here is an example using jQuery Dialog widget to edit span text

> http://jsfiddle.net/npch3/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can pass this to your function when you click on span like so:

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
      <span onclick="openPopup(this);">Name</span>
  </td>
  <td>
      <span onclick="openPopup(this);">Name</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

You will have to store the element so u can change it later when ure done with the popup.

```
 function openPopup(el) 
 { 
     // open popup and if button pressed
     el.innerHTML = yourNewText;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to achieve this:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ApsbC/7/

And the code snippet:

```
$(document).on("click","span",function(){

alert($(this).text());
// some popup code here
$(this).html("Some new Name");
});
```

EDIT:

I suggest though putting some class/id on those spans to have a better selector for the .**on()** method. So instead of having just **span** you could have something like **span.spanClass**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span onclick="openPopup(this);">Name</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span onclick="openPopup(this);">Name</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openPopup (o) {
    var newText = prompt("Enter some text: ");
    $(o).text(newText);
}
</script>
```